# How to make edit and delete buttons hidden if the user didn't create the content

Tags: laravel

I have an article , and I put edit , delete buttons but If I create another user I can delete the article.

this is my code :

```
 @auth
<div class="card-body">

    <div class="align-items-center">
        <a href="{{route('articles.edit', $article)}}" class="btn btn-warning">{{__("Edit")}}</a>
        <form method="post" action="{{route('articles.destroy', $article)}}" style="display: inline-block">
            @method('DELETE')
            @csrf
            <button onclick="return confirm('{{__("Are you sure you want to delete this article ?")}}')" class="btn btn-danger">{{__("Delete")}}</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    @endauth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the article user id.  If you don't track this, add a field to the Article model, `user_id`, which would show who wrote the article.  Then, you can easily create an if-check to make sure only the writer can delete or edit his own article.

On your blade page then:

```
@if($article->user_id === \Auth::user()->id)
     <div class="align-items-center">
    <a href="{{route('articles.edit', $article)}}" class="btn btn-warning">{{__("Edit")}}</a>
    <form method="post" action="{{route('articles.destroy', $article)}}" style="display: inline-block">
        @method('DELETE')
        @csrf
        <button onclick="return confirm('{{__("Are you sure you want to delete this article ?")}}')" class="btn btn-danger">{{__("Delete")}}</button>
    </form>
 </div>
@endif
```

And add a similar verification in your controller's `destroy()` method:

```
if($article->user_id === \Auth::user()->id)
   // Do the delete
else
   // return no-auth
```

Don't forget to add the current user to the `$article` when you save it (in the `store()` method of the controller):

```
$article->user_id = \Auth::user()->id
$article->save();
```

HTH

Comment: thanks man I appreciate your help . It worked like a charm

Comment: I do this kind of check all the time, so second nature :)  Glad it was helpful.